# TFS get only sources

Tags: tfs, version-control

In my case get latest version of some branch means download 50GB of data.
There is a lot of resources inside but I need only sources.

If it possible to download only one specific type instead of all data?

Update:
I ask about simple way .
If solution harder than installing VS plugin or couple lines in powershell/python using tf.exe then I will download 50GB once and try to code solution with TFS API on weekend.

Comment: Can't you go to source control explorer and select the node you want to get, right click and click on GetLatestVersion(Recursive) ?

Comment: Do you use TFS or Git CVS? Are you hard files located in a separate catalog? If you need only some files you can use API for downloading required artifacts. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet

Comment: @ThatAwesomeCoder I am not sure that I understand you correct. In my case sources located in many different folders. I think more than 100. Downloading each of it manually not easy work.

Comment: @Oxoron now I use pure TFS via 2013 VS. I also know that tf.exe tool exist. But I don't see simple way how to script what I want. High level API is good direction, but it looks like download 50 GB once much faster

Comment: The data is sparse or confined to a folder? In this latter case Cloak and you are good to go

Comment: Eduard's reply is great. Did you figure out  your problem follow his suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by [@Giulio Vian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100864/giulio-vian) you can cloak the paths you don't want to download before downloading.

Unfortunately you cannot cloak using wildcards, but you can use script approach in [How do I cloak multiple folders at a time in Team Foundation Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20004926/2621625) to cloak unneeded files.

In the script example shown in that answer you just need to come up with PowerShell "where" filter matching your case

```
Get-ChildItem | where {$_.PsIsContainer} | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.Name ; tf workfold /cloak $_.Name }
```

the details in the question is not provided to code exact filter. If you update your questions I can update this with "where" filter.