# TFS Not Deleting Artifacts From Source Control

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Oddly, source control seems to be holding onto files & projects even though I have deleted the artifacts from the Visual Studio Solution (itself).  The GetLatest brings down the correct files (even when I delete the underlying artifacts from my workspace by hand).  I have never seen this behavior in other servers...in fact...not even my PERSONAL Visual Studio Online behaves this way.

Now...to delete files...I have to delete things twice: once in the solution & once in TFS.

**MY QUESTIONS:**

- Why is TFS holding onto the files in Source Control?
- Is this a setting?
- How do we fix this?

This is an internal TFS server & I am not the administrator.  They are "new" so I am sure I will have to explain the issue at-length.

**FOR EXAMPLE:**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a normal phenomenon. **Team Foundation Server uses your workspace to keep track of what files you have downloaded and what version you have of them.**  The reason it does this is so that it can maintain your files without a costly sync step.  With TFS, when you say "Get latest", you only get the latest version of files that have changed since you last got them.

If you delete a file on the server and check that delete in, then when somebody does a "Get Latest", the file is deleted on their local system as well. It's for **keeping the local file system in sync with the servers**.

If you want to just delete the folder and files locally, there are two way to achieve it, more detail info please refer the answers in below question:[Delete Local Folder in TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19785117/delete-local-folder-in-tfs)