# Unable to get latest after branch to different area

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

I have a developer that I have created an Area for in visualstudio.com or tfs online.

The developer has limited access to only that area.

I have administration rights for everything and all areas.

I can branch and download stuff just fine in that area it's only when I move it outside that area.

When I branch from the developers Area to my main source tree I get
[image]

When I do that Get Specific Version I get the same error as above.  The red outline is just covering up my project names not highlighting anything.
[image]

All the files are in TFS online as they should be in this new branch I just can't understand what I'm missing?

When I choose to search for a changeset nothing appears either.

Comment: Did you give a try with `tf get command` instead of from GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please double check your account's permission related to that specific branch. Make sure there are not any **deny**. In TFS, deny trumps allow. You could use below command to list which users and AD groups have permissions to a folder and all sub folders in a TFS project.

```
 tf permission /server:<servername> <path in TFS>
```

And you could also use [tf get command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/get-command) instead of GUI in VS to see if it works.

Another way is trying to get changeset 1 and redownload the files from server. Detail steps please refer this: [Delete Local Folder in TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19785117/delete-local-folder-in-tfs)