# TFS Mapping to Local Folder Issues

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I'm clicking on a branch and mapping it to a local folder "C:\TFS", and then doing a get all..

The problem I'm encountering is that two or three of the sub-folders under root are not syncing.  The sub-folder is grayed out and the folder (and it's contents) are missing on my local drive. When I try to "get latest" on the grayed out folder, I get a message saying all is in sync and that I can force a sync with "override" commands.  I've tried doing just that (Advanced > Force Sync with override), but all I get is a message saying that all is in sync.

Thinking it may be a caching issue, I've tried re-naming the root folder, or deleting it and re-creating it.. I've also tried to map the TFS root to a whole new folder (new folder, new name, new location, etc.)..  I've tried everything I can think of.. but the same folders (and their contents) seem to be missing every time.

Any ideas on what this could be?  Any suggestions on a way to resolve this?

Ps. 
I'm using VS Pro 2013 - version 12.0.21005

Comment: Have you tried: right-click on the folder in VS/TFS > Advanced > Get Specific Version > select "overwrite"? Otherwise, check what is specified under File > Source Control > Advanced > Workspaces to see if something isn't explicitly overriding the top level workspace declaration.

Answer (score 3):

First, please double check your account's **permission** related to that specific sub-folders. Make sure there are not any **deny**. In TFS, deny trumps allow. You could use below command to list which users and AD groups have permissions to a folder and all sub folders in a TFS project.

```
 tf permission /server:<servername> <path in TFS>
```

Second, give a try with **Get Specific Version** to see if also get the same error as question above.

And you could also use [tf get command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/get-command) instead of GUI in VS to see if it works.

Another way is trying to get changeset 1 and redownload the files from server. Detail steps please refer this: [Delete Local Folder in TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19785117/delete-local-folder-in-tfs)

If all of above is not work, you may have to create a new workspace and delete the old one, which may do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a permissions issue.  Thank you for your help.