# Visual Studio Pending Changes not being updated

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have an older changeset that I had to get. Once the code was updated the results did not reflect in the pending changes. The files are indeed different than what is on the server, since I checked a few and it showed they were different. Is there a way to have the pending changes recheck for differences in the code so that it can be added to the pending changes automatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear TFS server knowledge of my local version?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587866/how-to-clear-tfs-server-knowledge-of-my-local-version)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I finally found that is the same question I was asking, just worded quite differently.

[How to clear TFS server knowledge of my local version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587866/how-to-clear-tfs-server-knowledge-of-my-local-version)